# MySQL: Error while adding foreign key to a table (no error code)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I have two tables - `topics` and `articles` and I'm trying to add a foreign key to `articles.arTopic` (normal index) which would reference `topics.topicId` (A-I PRIMARY key).

However, when I try to do that in phpMyAdmin, I get an error but without any error code whatsoever (it just says "Error"). Both tables are InnoDB and they are empty at the moment (tried it when they were populated with the same result), both columns are int(11) unsigned. `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` didn't show anything useful, the record in `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` section is unrelated to this problem.

I've been struggling with this for two hours and unless there's something blatanly obvious I'm missing, I have no idea what could be wrong. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Edited for SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
  `arId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `arText` longtext COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL,
  `arTopic` int(255) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`arId`),
  KEY `arTopic` (`arTopic`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `topics` (
  `topicId` int(255) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topicName` text COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`topicId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: Can you show us the SQL used to create the tables?

Comment: I will, once I figure out how to make it formatted properly... sorry, I'm a newbie.

Comment: Hey, are you sure that there's no more to that error? Perhaps there's something wrong with the page and the error message is being cut off? Also, have you tried in another browser just for kicks?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case, I even tried switching MyAdmin to another language to see if it wasn't just an non-translated error message. By the way, I've added my SQL to the question now.

Comment: I see no foreign key declaration in these statements. Further what exectly does the system report when you try to implement them with a foreign key?

Comment: Yeah, I'm adding the key now, but the tables were created a while ago, that's why it's not in the CREATE TABLE query. Like I said above in my question, the error report is just that, "Error".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There actually is a difference between the two columns - One column is `not null` and the other column is `Default null`. The difference will give you an error.

Comment: I played around with those values for a bit, didn't make a difference - whether they were both not null or null, it would end up in error.

Comment: @Štriky Start over with two tables, keep them empty and keep it simple. Keep adding attributes such as `null`, `not null` etc. until you get an error.

Comment: Uh, I'm a dumbass... I had another foreign key on that table and when I removed that, I could add the new one. After that I put back the old one and it worked, too. Sorry for wasting your time, guys. Evan, thanks a lot for your help - accepting your answer because it did make me go through the code again and helped me fix it.